# Using ARCloudAnchor for multiuser who are not in the same place

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I want to make a multi-user application with AR Cloud API but possible to see the anchors even if a person is in an other country.

Like create a virtual room for an international team that they will see all the anchors placed by each user of the team.

Answer (score 1):

**`Yes, it's possible`**, but when both real-world rooms (a.k.a. environments), where tracking will be performed, is visually identical (even if these rooms are in different countries). To create two identical and proper `3D feature maps`, that are able to share a common **AR Cloud Anchor**, two users have to move both Android devices around identical environments for up to 30 seconds.